# Kivy: How to call something on button on_press

Tags: android, python, kivy

I'm making an app that generates tickets. The generate script is already done.

When I press the button "Generera" ('Generate' in English) it should print the generated ticket (in a terminal for now).

It all runs but when I press the Generate button I get this error:

> AttributeError: StockholmTicket instance has no **call** method

I don't know how to call StockholmTicket on the gen_btn press and would appreciate any help.

Here is the code:

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import random


class Fejkbiljett(App):

    def build(self):
        gen_btn = Button(text='Generera',
                         size_hint=(.90, .10),
                         pos=(5, 5),
                         font_size=21)

        gen_btn.bind(on_press=StockholmTicket())

        l = BoxLayout()

        l.add_widget(gen_btn)

        return l


class StockholmTicket():

    def getMessage():
        # gNumbers
        gNumbers = random.randint(100, 999)
        gNumbers = str(gNumbers)

        gLetters = 'EAOXE'
        gLetters = gLetters * 2
        gLetters = ''.join(random.sample(gLetters, len(gLetters)))
        gLetters2 = 'EAOXA'
        gLetters2 = gLetters2 * 2
        gLetters2 = ''.join(random.sample(gLetters2, len(gLetters2)))
        gLetters3 = 'EAOXA'
        gLetters3 = gLetters3 * 2
        gLetters3 = ''.join(random.sample(gLetters3, len(gLetters3)))

        sCode = '123456789123456'
        sCode = ''.join(random.sample(sCode, len(sCode)))
        sCode = sCode[:6] + ' ' + sCode[6:]

        iPrice = '20'
        sPriceText = 'Red pris'
        sPricetype = 'R'
        mZones = 'A'
        mTime = datetime.now()
        mTime = mTime + timedelta(hours=1, minutes=15)
        mTime = str(mTime)
        mTime = mTime[11:16]
        mDate = str(datetime.now())
        mDate = mDate[:10]

        print((sPricetype + "-" + mZones + " " + mTime + " "
              + gNumbers + "\n\n"

              + gLetters + "\n"
              + gLetters2 + "\n"
              + gLetters3 + "\n"
              + "EEEEEEEEEE\n\n"

              + "SL biljett giltig till " + mTime + ", " + "\n" + mDate + "\n"
              + sPriceText + " " + iPrice + " kr ink 6% moms\n"

              + sCode + "\n"
              + "m.sl.se"))

    getMessage()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Fejkbiljett().run()
```

Comment: do what the error says. define a `call` method in `StockholmTicket`.

Comment: @njzk2 can you give me an example? I'm new to python (and programming in general) and this is the second real project I'm doing.

Comment: I suggest you read the doc for http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.event.html?highlight=button%20bind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why (my guess it he way that class is defined), but it doesn't work when called on a method that doesn't belong to the same class you are binding. You can create a method inside the class and the call the method in the other class. Like this:

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class Fejkbiljett(App):

    def build(self):
        self.gen_btn = Button(text='Generera',
                         size_hint=(.90, .10),
                         pos=(5, 5),
                         font_size=21)
        self.gen_btn.bind(on_press=self.getMessageFejkbiljett)
        l = BoxLayout()
        l.add_widget(self.gen_btn)
        return l

    def getMessageFejkbiljett(self, *args):
        print "1. this is called on the method getMessageFejkbiljett of Fejkbiljett"
        st = StockholmTicket()
        st.getMessage(self)


class StockholmTicket():

    def getMessage(self, source):
        source.gen_btn.text = "the event was called"
        print "2. this is called on the method getMessage of StockholmTicket"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Fejkbiljett().run()
```

Comment: Thanks! This also runs without errors, it wont print anything in the terminal however.

Comment: There might be something wrong with the terminal, but I changed the code so it also change the text in the button, `source.gen_btn.text = "the event was called"`. This code will test that the event is working properly. And you can make a very simple code to test if Kivy is printing in your terminal.

Comment: Wow, thanks. This works! And it prints it to the terminal. Will try with my code now! To be edited...

Comment: Edit: Everything works perfectly. Thank you. Can I ask you some follow up questions about Kivy and Android?

Comment: Glad it work. Just keep asking in stackoverflow. I frequently visit this site to help and ask, but I am not the only one that could help you so you will get faster replies, and we all can see the solutions.

Comment: I see. I was just gonna ask if it's possible to write something that will send you a sms locally (like a Fake SMS sender does from playstore), cause that's how I want the ticket to be displayed when this is finished, in a SMS. So before I continue, is that even possible with Kivy? Again, it's suppose to be locally and fake. Thank you :)

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no interface yet: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kivy-users/UTKBfg4wmog.

Answer (score 0):

The "StockholmTicket()" here is a class, which is not callable (unless you make it, but that's another discussion). Try using this code, which will create an instance which will hold the function to call.

```
    gen_btn.bind(on_press=StockholmTicket().getMessage)
```

instead of

```
    gen_btn.bind(on_press=StockholmTicket())
```

You also need to redefine the "getMessage" function as it does not yet accept parameters but it will need to. Try

```
class StockholmTicket():
    def getMessage(self, * args):
```

Hope that helps? Cheers

Comment: I tried what you did and now I get another error on line 72 "TypeError: getMessage() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)". I tried adding getMessage(self) and getMessage(* args) but neither works "undefined name 'self'". 

Any clues?

Comment: I suddenly realized why getMessage(self) didn't work, pretty obvious. But I tried getMessage(getMessage) which made more sense, it did actually load up the UI without errors, but when I press "Generate" nothing appears in the console/terminal, anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

But this works?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class Fejkbiljett(App):

    def build(self):
        gen_btn = Button(text='Generera',
                         size_hint=(.90, .10),
                         pos=(5, 5),
                         font_size=21)
        gen_btn.bind(on_press=StockholmTicket.getMessage)
        l = BoxLayout()
        l.add_widget(gen_btn)
        return l


class StockholmTicket(object):

    def getMessage(self):
        print "2. this is called on the method getMessage of StockholmTicket"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Fejkbiljett().run()
```

Comment: I actually got it working with this code https://gist.github.com/Mordaxx/77247acb7d86383278d3

Now the problem is that it generates the ticket inside the TextInput before I press 'Generate' ^^ Thanks for all help btw, much appreciated.

Comment: @ZenCODE I edited your answer by mistake. I am very sorry, I thought it was my answer up there. Please ignore the edition.

Answer (score 0):

you can just type gen_btn.on_press = your function